# "No converter found for return value of type: class org.stellar.sdk.requests.TransactionsRequestBuilder" when getting transaction history

Tags: transactions, accounts, java-sdk

This is my code for transaction history:

```
@RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.TRANS_HIS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody TransactionsRequestBuilder transactionHistory(@RequestBody stellarModel stellm) {
        logger.info("Start transactionHistory.");
        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(stellm.getSeed());
        TransactionsRequestBuilder tr = server.transactions().forAccount(source);
        return tr;
    }
```

It gives following error:

```
2019-04-15 11:47:01.839  WARN 18689 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter found for return value of type: class org.stellar.sdk.requests.TransactionsRequestBuilder]
```

I am stuck with this for two days,any help would be greatly apreciated

Try this as suggested:

```
@RequestMapping(value = StellRestURIConstants.TRANS_HIS, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ArrayList<TransactionResponse> transactionHistory(@RequestBody stellarModel stellm) {
        logger.info("Start transactionHistory.");
        ArrayList<TransactionResponse> arr = new ArrayList<TransactionResponse>();
        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(stellm.getSeed());

        TransactionsRequestBuilder tr = server.transactions().forAccount(source);
        try {
            arr = tr.execute().getRecords() ;
        } catch (TooManyRequestsException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("aaaaaaaa");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("bbbbbbb");

        }
        return arr;

    }
```

It gives below error:

```
"timestamp": "2019-04-15T10:34:50.439+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Could not write JSON: (was java.lang.NullPointerException); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->org.stellar.sdk.responses.TransactionResponse[\"sourceAccount\"]->org.stellar.sdk.KeyPair[\"secretSeed\"])",
    "path": "/transaction_history"
```

Comment: Absolutely no knowledge about java-sdk but i think forAccount might expect the public accountId as param, not the whole keypair. Its probably sth. like source.publicKey()

Comment: fromSecretSeed(stellm.getSeed()) will return account id

Comment: even in transaction it contain method to get account id :public TransactionsRequestBuilder forAccount(KeyPair account) {
    account = checkNotNull(account, "account cannot be null");
    this.setSegments("accounts", account.getAccountId(), "transactions");
    return this;
  }

Comment: Isn't `Keypair` a keypair object that represents both, secret seed and public id? I'd assume you have to pass the public String "G...." only.

Comment: Ok, seems different to the javascript sdk that I was working with.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Stellar. The error tells us that SpringFramework does not know how to convert `TransactionsRequestBuilder` to an HTTP response.

I suspect you don't want to return the builder, but the result of calling `.execute().getRecords()` on the builder.

*later...*

You tried this and got a new error message. Here's what I *think* is going on.

The `@ResponseBody` annotation tells spring to automatically convert your response object to JSON in the body of the response. For that to work, the return items needs to have accessible, non-null fields.

The Java SDK `KeyPair` object is used in the `TransactionResponse`, despite the response not containing the secret seed. The library sets the value as `null`. Spring doesn't know how to render this.

I'm not familiar with modern Spring, but I'm fairly certain this is what's happening. The long-term solution might be to modify the SDK so that the field is tagged as optional in a way Spring recognises. I don't know. That would take some investigation.

The immediate alternative for you is to not use `@ResponseBody`, but to use the `ResponseEntity` return type instead. This gives you the ability to map the `TransactionResponse` into a response directly. See the [Spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/) (search for ResponseEntity in that page).

Comment: Thanks for above answer i have edited question for details @Synesso

Comment: @user9862376 I've updated the answer, but without actually doing much research. Please take a look and report back if it is useful or useless or outright incorrect.